# How to update table with data from same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is table in SQL-Server:

```
Track(
 id uniqueindeficater,
 Track geography,
 the_geom geometry
)
```

Now i want take Track column and put this data into the_geom column converting it from geography to geometry data type. SOmething like this:

```
GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText(Track.Track.STAsText(),4326)
```

How can i update column using data from same table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
update
  Track
set
  the_geom = GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText(Track.STAsText(),4326)
```

Comment: Oh. Its really easy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't this work?

```
update track
    set the_geom = GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText(Track.Track.STAsText(),4326)
```